# How to copy Azure table

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to make a copy of an Azure table without actually reading its content. I was wondering if it is possible to make such copy, and whether it can be done from c#

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can backup an Azure Table to Blob Storage using C#. Doing this is very useful, for example to create regular backups of Table storage to Blobs for disaster recovery scenarios. Below is some code to do it. It uses [AzCopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/), which is a useful bulk Azure data movement utility which you can [here](http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy). I append a unique GUID to the filename below to prevent regular runs of this method overwriting the previously copied Azure Table.

```
public void ExportAzureTableToBlobStorage(string locationOfAzCopy, string sourceAccountName,
        string sourceKey, string sourceTable, string targetAccountName, string targetAccountKey,
        string targetContainerName,
        string targetFileName)
    {

        CreateBlobContainerIfItDoesntExist(targetAccountName, targetAccountKey, targetContainerName);

        string uniqueFileIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string uniqueManifestIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        string uniqueTargetFileName = $"{targetFileName}_{uniqueFileIdentifier}";
        string arguments =
            $@"/source:https://{sourceAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/{sourceTable} /sourceKey:{sourceKey
                } 
            /dest:https://{targetAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{targetContainerName
                }/ /Destkey:{targetAccountKey} 
            /manifest:{uniqueTargetFileName
                } /V:.\Files\ExportLog_{uniqueManifestIdentifier}.log /Z:.\Files\ExportJnl_{uniqueManifestIdentifier
                }.jnl";

        //Configure the process in which to launch AzCopy
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = locationOfAzCopy,
                Arguments = arguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            var runReportMessage = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            //Inspect runReportMessage or whatever you need to do with it. 
        }
    }
```

Here's the method to automatically create the Blob Container specified if it doesn't already exist:

```
private void CreateBlobContainerIfItDoesntExist(string targetAccountName, string targetAccountKey, string containerName)
    {
        var blobClient = GetCloudBlobClient(GenerateBlobStorageConnectionString(targetAccountName, targetAccountKey));
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

        //Create a new container, if it does not exist
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is about copying the Azure table entities, you can use Azcopy, please refer to the post below for details.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#copy-entities-in-an-azure-table-with-azcopy-preview-version-only